# Send CSV file in response through REST API

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5

I need to send a CSV file through rest api. 
I am using **reactjs** for front end development and constructing backend apis with **Laravel**. 
I am confused with how to send a CSV file through api response ? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What code have you written so far? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I have constructed a csv file with Maatwebsite and I am confused that how to send it through api response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function will download csv file

```
public function downloadCSV(Request $request){
        $table = User::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->get();
        $filename = "users.csv";
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
        fputcsv($handle, array('user_name','user_email','country','state','address','zip_code','city'));
        foreach($table as $row) {
            fputcsv($handle, array(
                $row['user_name'],
                $row['user_email'],
                $row['country'],
                $row['state'],
                $row['address'],
                $row['zip_code'],
                $row['city']
            ));
        }
        fclose($handle);
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'text/csv');
        return response()->download($filename, 'users.csv', $headers);
    }
```

Comment: I have nearly twenty + columns what should I do now in which columns are dynamic in nature

Comment: @Jayashree , you need to dynamically execute loop through columns and print data